# Does every class in same package needs to extend Application?

Tags: java

I am making a project in javafx. All my classes are included in a package. Is there a need to extend Application to all the classes ? If not, how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Application is an entry point for JavaFX applications. Can can have only one class that inherit from it in your application.

Comment: How to write other classes then ?

Comment: In the normal way. A class is a type declaration. You should try a Java tutorial. It would clear up for you the way.